# Java G1GC sudden System usage spike 100%

Tags: java, garbage-collection, load, g1gc

We are using java 1.8.144_b_01. We have a problem where G1GC sys usage spike suddenly eg: from 1 to 113 , 140 which is very high than user space cpu usage.

At that time Object Copy time becomes very high ~10 times the normal , i see the following logs very often:

> 2018-03-09T14:55:30.111+0530: 45966.639: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation
>   Pause) (young) **(to-space exhausted)**, 2.1706858 secs]

After this the load avg. start to spike up > 100 and when i see in top i see all the cpu is taken by sys space and mostly it shows 100% there.

All this happens suddenly ~ some fixed time daily on AWS. Sometimes application run without issue for 10 days, sometime daily around same time we see the issue . The usage pattern remain exactly the same every day.

What should i do next?

```
   [Eden: 2656.0M(13.5G)->0.0B(13.7G) Survivors: 440.0M->592.0M Heap: 14.2G(23.2G)->2547.0M(23.8G)]
 [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=1.76 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:26.647+0530: 45963.175: [GC pause (GCLocker Initiated GC) (young) (initial-mark), 0.1116088 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 97.9 ms, GC Workers: 16]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 45963178.4, Avg: 45963178.6, Max: 45963178.8, Diff: 0.4]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 5.7, Avg: 6.6, Max: 12.7, Diff: 7.0, Sum: 104.9]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 40.7, Avg: 47.1, Max: 47.7, Diff: 7.0, Sum: 753.2]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 181, Avg: 226.9, Max: 310, Diff: 129, Sum: 3631]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 3.8, Avg: 4.1, Max: 4.2, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 64.9]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 38.2, Avg: 38.8, Max: 39.3, Diff: 1.1, Sum: 620.9]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 16]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 1.3]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 96.3, Avg: 96.6, Max: 96.8, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 1545.4]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 45963275.1, Avg: 45963275.2, Max: 45963275.3, Diff: 0.2]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.4 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.6 ms]
   [Other: 12.7 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 5.6 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.5 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 1.3 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.6 ms]
   [Eden: 592.0M(13.7G)->0.0B(13.8G) Survivors: 592.0M->504.0M Heap: 4605.8M(23.8G)->2469.3M(23.8G)]
 [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:26.760+0530: 45963.287: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
2018-03-09T14:55:26.798+0530: 45963.325: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-end, 0.0379580 secs]
2018-03-09T14:55:26.798+0530: 45963.325: [GC concurrent-mark-start]
2018-03-09T14:55:27.851+0530: 45964.379: [GC concurrent-mark-end, 1.0532587 secs]
2018-03-09T14:55:27.877+0530: 45964.405: [GC remark 2018-03-09T14:55:27.878+0530: 45964.405: [Finalize Marking, 0.0035673 secs] 2018-03-09T14:55:27.881+0530: 45964.409: [GC ref-proc, 0.0021035 secs] 2018-03-09T14:55:27.883+0530: 45964.411: [Unloading, 0.0291335 secs], 0.0380596 secs]
 [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:27.942+0530: 45964.470: [GC cleanup 6702M->6702M(23G), 0.0086775 secs]
 [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:30.111+0530: 45966.639: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) (to-space exhausted), 2.1706858 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 1692.2 ms, GC Workers: 16]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 45966642.3, Avg: 45966642.5, Max: 45966642.7, Diff: 0.4]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 1.3, Avg: 3.9, Max: 12.1, Diff: 10.7, Sum: 62.8]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 30.6, Avg: 37.9, Max: 38.5, Diff: 7.9, Sum: 605.8]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 166, Avg: 246.8, Max: 343, Diff: 177, Sum: 3949]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 4.0, Avg: 4.1, Max: 4.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 65.6]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 1640.6, Avg: 1645.6, Max: 1647.7, Diff: 7.1, Sum: 26329.1]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.2, Max: 0.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 2.4]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 4.2, Max: 6, Diff: 5, Sum: 67]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.7]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 1691.5, Avg: 1691.7, Max: 1691.8, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 27066.6]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 45968334.1, Avg: 45968334.2, Max: 45968334.2, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.3 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.7 ms]
   [Other: 477.5 ms]
      [Evacuation Failure: 302.2 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 159.1 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 1.1 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.6 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 9.6 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.3 ms]
   [Eden: 1768.0M(13.8G)->0.0B(13.5G) Survivors: 504.0M->176.0M Heap: 14.1G(23.8G)->4432.1M(24.0G)]
 [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=2.17 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:32.555+0530: 45969.083: [GC pause (G1 Humongous Allocation) (young) (initial-mark), 0.1336821 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 105.7 ms, GC Workers: 16]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 45969086.4, Avg: 45969086.6, Max: 45969086.7, Diff: 0.3]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 5.8, Avg: 6.6, Max: 13.2, Diff: 7.4, Sum: 105.1]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 72.0, Avg: 78.6, Max: 79.4, Diff: 7.4, Sum: 1258.2]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 243, Avg: 337.2, Max: 502, Diff: 259, Sum: 5396]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.4, Avg: 0.7, Max: 0.8, Diff: 0.5, Sum: 11.8]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 18.0, Avg: 18.4, Max: 18.6, Diff: 0.6, Sum: 294.7]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.1, Max: 2, Diff: 1, Sum: 18]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 1.0]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 104.3, Avg: 104.4, Max: 104.6, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 1670.9]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 45969191.0, Avg: 45969191.0, Max: 45969191.1, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.6 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.6 ms]
   [Other: 26.8 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 19.6 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.1 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.8 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.0 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.4 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.2 ms]
   [Eden: 392.0M(13.5G)->0.0B(13.3G) Survivors: 176.0M->224.0M Heap: 5148.1M(24.0G)->4486.3M(24.0G)]
 [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.14 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:32.689+0530: 45969.217: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-start]
2018-03-09T14:55:32.751+0530: 45969.279: [GC concurrent-root-region-scan-end, 0.0620086 secs]
2018-03-09T14:55:32.751+0530: 45969.279: [GC concurrent-mark-start]
2018-03-09T14:55:34.004+0530: 45970.531: [GC concurrent-mark-end, 1.2523056 secs]
2018-03-09T14:55:34.031+0530: 45970.559: [GC remark 2018-03-09T14:55:34.031+0530: 45970.559: [Finalize Marking, 0.0036417 secs] 2018-03-09T14:55:34.035+0530: 45970.563: [GC ref-proc, 0.0171440 secs] 2018-03-09T14:55:34.052+0530: 45970.580: [Unloading, 0.0319188 secs], 0.0563588 secs]
 [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:34.115+0530: 45970.642: [GC cleanup 8540M->8540M(24G), 0.0092065 secs]
 [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:35.889+0530: 45972.417: [GC pause (G1 Humongous Allocation) (young) (to-space exhausted), 1.5352217 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 1216.7 ms, GC Workers: 16]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 45972420.7, Avg: 45972420.9, Max: 45972421.1, Diff: 0.4]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 1.7, Avg: 3.2, Max: 10.8, Diff: 9.0, Sum: 51.4]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 44.0, Avg: 45.0, Max: 45.5, Diff: 1.4, Sum: 719.4]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 209, Avg: 295.3, Max: 401, Diff: 192, Sum: 4725]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 7.5, Avg: 7.9, Max: 8.0, Diff: 0.5, Sum: 125.9]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 1153.4, Avg: 1160.0, Max: 1161.4, Diff: 8.0, Sum: 18559.9]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 2.1]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 16]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.8]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 1216.0, Avg: 1216.2, Max: 1216.4, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 19459.4]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 45973637.0, Avg: 45973637.1, Max: 45973637.1, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.3 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.9 ms]
   [Other: 317.3 ms]
      [Evacuation Failure: 302.0 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.5 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 1.3 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.5 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 7.7 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.4 ms]
   [Eden: 2504.0M(13.3G)->0.0B(1224.0M) Survivors: 224.0M->0.0B Heap: 15.5G(24.0G)->6956.9M(24.0G)]
 [Times: user=5.67 sys=0.11, real=1.53 secs] 
2018-03-09T14:55:38.964+0530: 45975.492: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (mixed), 0.1187935 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 95.2 ms, GC Workers: 16]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 45975495.3, Avg: 45975495.5, Max: 45975495.8, Diff: 0.5]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 4.3, Avg: 5.7, Max: 13.8, Diff: 9.5, Sum: 91.2]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 64.9, Avg: 73.0, Max: 74.3, Diff: 9.4, Sum: 1167.3]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 268, Avg: 343.9, Max: 491, Diff: 223, Sum: 5503]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 1.7, Avg: 2.0, Max: 2.1, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 32.4]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
:
```

VM parameters are:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=1000000
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500
-Xmx24576m
-Xloggc:/tmp/gc/gc-%t.log
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:G1ReservePercent=20
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:MaxPermSize=768m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=20
-Xms10480m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of things going on at the same time. Due to `InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=20` it seems to be starting concurrent marking cycles continously.

Multiple entries of `GC pause (G1 Humongous Allocation)` indicate that you're contiously allocating very large objects and there is not enough contiguous free space to accommodate them, presumably due to the previously allocated ones not having been collected yet or [due to heap fragmentation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173627), again caused by the huge allocations.

> (to-space exhausted)

At this point this is just the icing on the cake, the collector can't find enough room to move objects and has to prematurely tenure regions in place.

You should run your application under an allocation profiler and optimize your code reduce the bursts of huge, short-lived objects.

Comment: I just checked and found out that whenever the issue comes GCLocker initiated gc pause frequency is high. Will work on improvement of application , still my question is this burst comes sometimes only , otherwise on same load application run well on 10 days also

Comment: If some more data is needed , let me know

Comment: `GCLocker Initiated GC` are caused by JNI code requiring objects not to move and thus deferring GCs until the lock is released. You could try Shenandoah since it supports region-pinning and doesn't have to lock out the collector.

Comment: But I think the humongous objects are a bigger concern since they can force the collector to move around a lot of memory, thus affecting copy times.

Comment: any hints on how to debug the sudden unusual spike

Comment: Thanks, we found the answer by opening the heap in jvisualvm , which showed which object was very big and we narrowed it down to the application problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to come off as absolutely off the wall, but you most likely have a memory leak or a hanging run thread. For memory leaks, you'll just have to experiment until something works. However, for a hanging run thread you just need to make sure there is a Thread.sleep function inside of every Runnable Thread.

Comment: i doubt on memory leaks, as sometimes system recover automatically, in that case i didn't find to-space exhausted, but system space CPU usage spike and load avg. spike > 100 in that case also